# How to change the font color of SageMath terminal version 9.5?

Tags: shell, sage

I am rocking a Ubuntu 22.04 laptop, so I am stuck to SageMath v9.5, instead of the current version as of today. The font is currently blue, which is not the best match at all with the default purple terminal background. How could I change the color to, let's say, green?

I've tried something in [this link](https://ask.sagemath.org/question/10060/sage-terminal-colors/), but the approach is so old, it doesn't apply to this version anymore. I can type `%colors Linux` at the Sage shell itself, but it resets whenever I log off.

Comment: Did you try the answer from Sébastien at the link you posted?

Comment: Yeah, the c.InteractiveShell.colors thing seems more modern.

Comment: [Sébastien's Ask Sage answer](https://ask.sagemath.org/question/10060/sage-terminal-colors/?answer=36036#post-id-36036) should work (and it should have more upvotes!).

Answer (score 1):

> I've tried something in this link, but the approach is so old, it
> doesn't apply to this version anymore. I can type %colors Linux at the
> Sage shell itself, but it resets whenever I log off.

You have to save the command `%colors Linux` into **init.sage** file which will be save at location **~/.sage/init.sage** you can flow the below steps to achieve this

1. Open the Terminal by pressing keys <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> or from all programs
2. Go to ~/.sage directory by using `cd ~/.sage` command
3. Enter `touch init.sage` to create a file by the name init.sage
4. Open the file with an editor like vim/nano etc
5. Now write the command `%colors Linux` and save the file and close it
6. New font color will not change after restarting `sage`

Answer (score 0):

You can change the font colour of the terminal by modifying the Sage Terminal profile in the terminal's preferences.

1. Open the terminal in SageMath.
2. Go to Edit > Profile Preferences.
3. In the Profile Preferences window, select the Colours tab.
   4.Under Text colour, you can use the colour picker to select a new font colour for the terminal.
   5.Click Close to apply the changes and close the window.